# Adding Second LED strip and power supply to controller

Tags: dc, led-strip

Excuse the quality of the picture below.

I have a single power supply connected to an LED controller and a single LED strip. I would like to add a second LED strip but will need to add another power supply. Could someone please tell me how this needs to be wired?

[image]

Comment: Current flows in a loop - thus you need to connect all the 0V points together

Comment: Thanks @Kartman I have made changes to the picture. Would that be correct?

Comment: no. that would most likely damage almost everything in that picture.

Comment: It might be easier to wire the power supplies in parallel. A better idea would be to just get a larger power supply. As well, are you using adequate gauge wire and wiring the mains to the power supplies in a legal and safe manner?